# Google Cloud ML: I want to recognize Korea license plate

Tags: machine-learning, cloud, google-cloud-ml

I want to recognize Korea license plate.
So, I tried to predicted South Korean license plates using Google Cloud ML.
But, Fail to predicted. Google Cloud ML not recognize Korean language part.
How do I train to recognize the Korean part?
The final goal is save Korean license plates using OCR.

Comment: Can you please provide more information, such as the error message, the output of `saved_model_cli show --all --dir /path/to/model`, the command you used to perform prediction, and the payload you sent.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ],
      "image": {
        "source": {
          "imageUri": "http://t1.daumcdn.net/liveboard/mrpic/fac5cab6a8bb4ea2b3447cc01bd8b097.JPG"
        }
      },
      "imageContext": {
        "languageHints": [
          "ko"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```